# How to "lazy load" post thumbnail

Tags: images

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium-thumbnail', array( 'loading' => false ), [ 'alt' => esc_html ( get_the_title() ) ] );  ?>
```

Get Diagnostics info on pagespeed

Largest Contentful Paint image was not lazily loaded

what I wrong?

Comment: You’re literally telling it not to: `'loading' => false`.

Comment: To expand on @JacobPeattie's comment: `the_post_thumbnail()` eventually calls [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/), and the `loading` value defaults to `lazy`. (If I'm reading it right, this was first added in v. 5.5.0.) So you really don't need to pass anything in the `$attr` array if you want lazy loading.

Comment: Thanks
But still have this error after removing this line.
Can I create custom PHP function tags from the_post_thumbnail() to my_custom_thumbnail() with lazy loading and support to custom image size, eg.i have use for medium-thumbnail.

Comment: A new function isn’t going to help. If the loading attribute isn’t working you likely have some other problem and a custom function won’t help.

Comment: problem is solved for lazy load using the_post_thumbnail( 'medium-thumbnail' ); but not solve pagespeed
Largest Contentful Paint image was not lazily loaded

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', array( 'loading' => 'lazy' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**single-post.php:**

```
<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('medium') ?>" class="img-fluid rounded shadow-3 mb-1" alt="<?php the_title() ?>" loading="lazy">
```

- the_post_thumbnail_url('medium')
- Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages:
  https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/

Answer (score 0):

```php
    add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wpdd_modify_post_thumbnail_html', 10, 5 );
    /**
     * Add `loading="lazy"` attribute to images output by the_post_thumbnail().
     *
     * @param  string $html The post thumbnail HTML.
     * @param  int $post_id The post ID.
     * @param  string $post_thumbnail_id    The post thumbnail ID.
     * @param  string|array $size   The post thumbnail size. Image size or array of width and height values (in that order). Default 'post-thumbnail'.
     * @param  string $attr Query string of attributes.
     * 
     * @return string   The modified post thumbnail HTML.
     */
    function wpdd_modify_post_thumbnail_html( $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr ) {
    
        return str_replace( '<img', '<img loading="lazy"', $html );
    
    }
```

source: https://wpdevdesign.com/native-lazy-loading-responsive-images-in-wordpress/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).